# Finding phrase in specified files v2 c++

Tags: c++, strings, file

Please provide constructive feedback so I can learn from my mistakes. Please tell me what I did right and where I came up with very good solution and where I should improve. Here is the code (Please pardon some indentation, formatting errors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct occurrence
{
    std::string fileName;
    int line;
    int firstChar;
};

// Function used to search for a phrase in a file and save records to occurrences vector.
void searchInFile(std::ifstream* file, std::string fileName, std::string phrase, std::vector <occurrence>* occurrences);
// Function used to search through occurrences vector and return how many of occurrences were found in file with specified name.
int countOccurrencesInFile(std::vector <occurrence> occurrences, std::string file);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    std::string phrase;
    if(argc < 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Please specify what phrase to look for and file names to look for a phrase in.\n"
                  << "For more information and instructions please read README.txt file, which is\n"
                  << "in the same directory as this program.";
        return 0;
    }
    phrase = argv[1];
    std::vector <occurrence> occurrences;
    // Starting from 2, because we are ommiting argv[0] which is name of our program and argv[1] which is phrase.
    for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
    {   
        std::ifstream file(argv[i]);
        if(!file)
        {
            std::cout << "Error opening a file: " << argv[i] << "\n";
            continue;
        }
        searchInFile(&file, std::string(argv[i]), phrase, &occurrences);
    }

    std::cout << "Search Completed!\n";
    if(!occurrences.empty())
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < occurrences.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                std::cout << countOccurrencesInFile(occurrences, occurrences[0].fileName);
                std::cout << " occurrences found in file " << occurrences[0].fileName << "\n";
                std::cout << "\tLine: " << occurrences[0].line << ", position: " << occurrences[0].firstChar;
            }
            else if(i > 0)
            {
                if(occurrences[i].fileName != occurrences[i - 1].fileName)
                {
                    std::cout << countOccurrencesInFile(occurrences, occurrences[i].fileName);
                    std::cout << " occurrences found in file " << occurrences[i].fileName << "\n";
                }
                if(occurrences[i].line != occurrences[i - 1].line)
                {
                    std::cout << "\n\tLine: " << occurrences[i].line << ", position: " << occurrences[i].firstChar;
                    continue;
                }
                std::cout << ", " << occurrences[i].firstChar;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Sorry, no occurrences were found.";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void searchInFile(std::ifstream* file, std::string fileName, std::string phrase, std::vector <occurrence>* occurrences)
{
    int lineNumber = 1;
    std::string line;
    int startFrom = 0;
    while(!(*file).eof())
    {
        std::getline(*file, line);
        while(line.find(phrase, startFrom) != -1)
        {   
            occurrence* ptrOccurrence = nullptr;
            ptrOccurrence = new occurrence;
            (*ptrOccurrence).firstChar = line.find(phrase, startFrom) + 1;
            (*ptrOccurrence).line = lineNumber;
            (*ptrOccurrence).fileName = fileName;
            (*occurrences).push_back(*ptrOccurrence);
            delete ptrOccurrence;
            startFrom = line.find(phrase, startFrom) + phrase.size();
        }
        lineNumber++;
        startFrom = 0;
    }
}

int countOccurrencesInFile(std::vector <occurrence> occurrences, std::string file)
{
    int numberOfOccurrences = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < occurrences.size(); i++)
    {
        if(occurrences[i].fileName == file)
        {
            numberOfOccurrences++;
        }
    }
    return numberOfOccurrences;
}
```

Comment: If you get alerts on this site these are rarely meant as jokes.

Comment: what to you think i should? i think i provided enough details. if you have better idea share dont be selfish. why did you delete poem part anyway?

Comment: The title of the question is good. We expect users to expand on that in a bit more detail in the question itself, to help reviewers understand the purpose of the code better, and be able to give better reviews. If the site asks you for something, for example to provide more detail, please try to comply, rather than circumvent it.

Comment: As I stated before, I do not think I need to add any more details, but for the good of this lovely site and community I am willing to obey the norms around here. Thank you for your helpful explanation and the nature of your answer which I read with pleasure, in contrast to πάντα ῥεῖ's rather sarcastic and not helpful at all attitude. I was also disgusted by the fact that he did't enjoy such a noble poem! (this is joke as well). Anyway, have a nice day everybody!!

Answer (score 1):

Just some quick notes for possible improvements (strictly according to *my* taste)...

- refrain from using `continue` instead of `else`
- use references instead of pointers (e.g. for *file* or std::vector)
- consider using the `->` operator instead of `(*).`
- don't use `new`/`delete` here, just `push_back` a local instance (this will even avoid copying in recent C++ compilers)
- don't use `int` for indexing `std::vector`
- use (at least) compiler option `-Wall`
- consider using `const` (e.g. for *phrase*)
- consider initialization of members (*line* and *firstChar* in *occurrence*)
- naming should be more consistent, don't use *file* for a `std::string` *and* for a `std::istream*`
- passing `std::vector` by value is expensive, use a `const &`

Comment: Thanks!!! Very helpful!!! But i figured out a way i could shorten this code from 130 lines to 25.... embarrassing isnt it?